# File 'cypress/**/*.js' not found when running tsc command. Success if file is specified

Tags: typescript, npm

I want to run this tsc command for all .js files inside the cypress folder

```
npx tsc --noEmit --pretty --allowJs
```

So i add 'cypress/**/*.js'

```
npx tsc --noEmit --pretty --allowJs cypress/**/*.js
```

But it return this error

```
error TS6053: File 'cypress/**/*.js' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

However when i run the command with specific file, it works

```
npx tsc --noEmit --pretty --allowJs cypress/e2e/sub-folder/test-files.cy.js
```